# angularjs: ng-view condition request scheme

Tags: angularjs

I'm serving on both http and https
when the requests's scheme is http it should

`<div ng-show="condition">Go to https</div>`

Now what would that condition be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, $location is a service which can help you parse the URL in the browser URL bar.

You could use $location.protocol() to get the request's protocol.

**JS**

```
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope, $location){
    $scope.isHttp=$location.protocol()==="http"?true:false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-show="isHttp">
    <a href="https://your.domain/target">Go to https</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

DEMO: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr58J/2/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way but it's a way.

I created a controller

```
.controller('SchemeController', ['$scope','$location', function($scope,$location){
    $scope.scheme = $location.protocol();
}]);
```

and HTML

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="SchemeController" ng-show="scheme == 'http'">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        My warning text here
    </div>
</div>
```